# Computer emulator code execution

Tags: c#, virtual-machine

I am trying to create a MC6808 microprocessor emulator.  My program works all the up to the point of entering the object code into my virtual machine.  The next step is to execute the program which is where my question comes from.

What is the most efficient way to ***interpret*** all of the codes(instructions) that are in (virtual)memory?   Since each code performs a specific behavior(add, subtract, shift, etc.) involving the MC6808 registers the only solution I can think of is to use a series of IF statements for each of the 197 available codes.

```
    if (Instruction == 0x86) // LDAA #Value
   {
    accumulatorA = MC6800[(InstructionPointer + 1)];//Value location
    ProgLength -= 1;
    InstructionPointer += 2;
        UpdateRegisterStatus();
   }
```

I have a MC6800 class that contains all of the registers, memory stack, address pointers, etc. and I have a list of all of the available mnemonics:

```
        //List sample
        mnemonicsList.Add(new Mnemonics("ABA" , 0, 5, 0x1B, 1, 2, 4));
        mnemonicsList.Add(new Mnemonics("ADCA", 1, 1, 0x89, 2, 2, 1));
        mnemonicsList.Add(new Mnemonics("ADCA", 2, 2, 0x99, 2, 3, 1));
        mnemonicsList.Add(new Mnemonics("ADCA", 3, 3, 0xA9, 2, 5, 1));
        mnemonicsList.Add(new Mnemonics("ADCA", 4, 4, 0xB9, 3, 4, 1));
        mnemonicsList.Add(new Mnemonics("ADCB", 1, 1, 0xC9, 2, 2, 2));
        mnemonicsList.Add(new Mnemonics("ADCB", 2, 2, 0xD9, 2, 3, 2));
        mnemonicsList.Add(new Mnemonics("ADCB", 3, 3, 0xE9, 2, 5, 2));
        mnemonicsList.Add(new Mnemonics("ADCB", 4, 4, 0xF9, 3, 4, 2));

        //LIST KEY:  mnemonic, operand type, addressing mode, object code,
        //byte size, machine cycles, register used
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1):

Standard approaches for large number of conditions are `swtich` and dictionary or actions ([Refactor long switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586041/refactor-long-switch-statement)).