# Is there a good way to refactor this switch statement?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, refactoring, case

I have a switch statement right now that looks pretty chunky. It works but it's pretty chunky and repetitive because I actually have another switch statement like it (that takes a different varaible).

```
if (time == 15)
{
    percent = policyGroup[0];
} 
else
{
    percent = policyGroup[1];
}

var currentVal = Convert.ToDouble(profit[i]);
switch (CSR[i])
{
    case "Buford":
        Buford += currentVal * percent;
        break;
    case "Cain":
        Cain += currentVal * percent;
        break;
    case "Young":
        Young += currentVal * percent;
        break;
    case "Thomas":
        Thomas += currentVal * percent;
        break;
    case "Armendt":
        Armendt += currentVal * percent;
        break;
    case "Vanover":
        Vanover += currentVal * percent;
        break;
    case "Phillips":
        Phillips += currentVal * percent;
        break;
    case "Smalley":
        Smalley += currentVal * percent;
        break;
    case "Pitman":
        Pitman += currentVal * percent;
        break;
    case "Huse":
        Huse += currentVal * percent;
        break;
    case "Nichols":
        Nichols += currentVal * percent;
        break;
}
```

Comment: A Dictionary or using reflection....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refactor long switch statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586041/refactor-long-switch-statement)

Comment: if those variables are immutable type then you can only do it with reflection

Answer (score 3):

The part that must look really chunky as well is the declaration of all the variables:

```
double Buford = 0, Cain = 0, Young, Thomas, Armendt, ..., Pitman;
```

These variables should not be hard-coded; instead, you should use an associative container that stores all per-name values:

```
IDictionary<string,double> valByName = new Dictionary<string,double> {
    {"Buford", 0}
,   {"Pitman", 0}
};
```

Now you can do this:

```
valByName[CSR[i]] = currentVal * percent;
```