# How to refactor a switch, return values and call async methods at once

Tags: c#, dictionary, switch-statement, refactoring

I'm actually using this switch and wanted to refactor it since it can grow significantly depending in my application's uses.

```
switch (something)
{
    case "emisores":
        return await StampEmisor(id);
    case "tipodocumento":
        return await StampTipoDocumento(id);
    case "plantillas":
        return await StampPlantilla(id);
    default:
        return BadApiRequest("blabla was not found.");
}
```

I need to:

1.- Return values

2.- Pass parameters

3.- Call async methods

I tried following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586041/refactor-long-switch-statement#22109763) but those 3 conditions aren't applying. How could I perform this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to return values (1st requirement) you will have to convert the `Action` inside the `Dictionary` to `Function`:

```
new Dictionary<string, Func<>>()
```

Since that implicitly makes this returning `TResult`, you will have to specify what you're returning **as the last parameter inside the** `Func` **definition itself**, and specifying **in first place the parameter you're passing** (2nd requirement).

Which gets finally into

```
var stamps = new Dictionary<string, Func<Guid, Task<HttpResponseMessage>>>()
{
    { "emisores", new Func<Guid,Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(StampEmisor) },
    { "tipodocumento",new Func<Guid,Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(StampTipoDocumento)},
    { "plantillas", new Func<Guid,Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(StampPlantilla)},
    { "reglas", new Func<Guid, Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(StampRegla) }
};
```

Now, in order to call it *awaitedly* (3rd condition) just call the `.Invoke(id)` with the `await` statement. In this case, `return await` because we want to return the provided value:

```
if (stamps.ContainsKey(entity))
    return await stamps[entity].Invoke(id);
```

Comment: Use `TryGetValue` rather than `ContainsKey`.

Comment: It is perfectly legitimate if one answers his or her question, even if he or she asks the question already knowing the answer. I was going to write something similar to this answer and seen the asker has already done it.